# How to write Node.js REPL that works with GNU Emacs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, emacs, scheme, readline

I have Scheme interpreter in JavaScript called LIPS. I have executable file, it works in terminal emulator but it's broken in GNU Emacs inferior mode (using `run-scheme` function).

I've reproduced the issue with this simple Node.js REPL using Readline:

```js
var prompt = 'lips> ';
var continuePrompt = '... ';
const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout,
    prompt: prompt,
    terminal: !!process.stdin.isTTY // true in Emacs
});
if (process.stdin.isTTY) {
    rl.prompt();
}

rl.on('line', function(line) {
    if (process.stdin.isTTY) {
        rl.prompt();
    }
});
```

First issue was that when I type something the output is duplicated, it's literal command line echo:

```
lips> 10
10
10
lips> '(1 2 3)
'(1 2 3)
(1 2 3)
lips>
```

I've found solution, which:

```
(setq comint-process-echoes t)
```

But another issue is that on resize it keep appending prompt to prompt. so I have this:

```
lips> lips> lips> lips> lips>
```

This is prompt because if I set:

```
(setq comint-prompt-read-only t)
```

I can't delete that text.

**EDIT:**

The same happen if I call (read) that is also using readline to get input, it keep adding spaces.

I was [reading Node.js source code](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/2070d3f8eb14ca9cc5c2e23824b20d700d7183be/lib/repl.js) and it also use readline and it works fine when run using `run-js`, Kawa Scheme Interpreter works correctly but it don't use readline:

```
 (setq inferior-js-program-command "node --interactive")
 (run-js)
```

This works, it's not run-scheme but it's same mode, I've also tried to run same `run-js` code but with my Scheme interpreter, and it also show same prompt duplication on resize.

```
 (setq inferior-js-program-command "/home/kuba/projects/jcubic/lips/bin/lips.js")
 (run-js)
```

Comment: @picklerick it's default comint mode from run-scheme command, the same is with `emacs -q`, by resize I mean draging edge of the frame in emacs so window with buffer resize and refresh.

Comment: @picklerick  It's comint mode because `comint-prompt-read-only` option works with scheme. But this is mainly question about Node.js, Why the app is broken but guile work fine? I'm not sure if guile or kawa use readline. But of course maybe there is a way to handle this in Emacs, by knowing why it's broken Emacs maybe I will be able to fix in Node.

Comment: @picklerick How should I write Node.js REPL app, so it work with comint mode? I want scheme not normal term, I know it works in ansi-term.

Comment: @picklerick I want to write Node.js app and run it with `run-scheme` in GNU EMacs (`run-scheme` use comint mode). I don't know how I can explain you that. Guile scheme works with `run-scheme` it also works with terminal, how can I write Node.js app that work the same as guile.

Comment: @picklerick I call `(run-scheme "/usr/bin/guile")` the major-mode is inerior-scheme-mode, same if I can run the function with my node.js executable, and setting `comint-prompt-read-only` change how it behave, I'm not how it's affected if it's not comint mode. I'm using GNU Emacs 26.3 on Fedora.

Comment: @picklerick do you how to make Node.js app that work with that version? Code that also works in terminal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got [answer in Emacs devel mailing list](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2020-04/msg01070.html), the solution is to turn off readline when inside Emacs:

```js
const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout,
    prompt: prompt,
    terminal: !!process.stdin.isTTY && !(process.env.EMACS || process.env.INSIDE_EMACS)
});
```

Lot of interpreters do the same thing. e.g: Bash.